# How to send image from database as email attachment using android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to send an image that users puts into SQLite DB as an attachment via email.
Currently the image is stored as byte[] and with this code I can decode it:

```
Image dbHelper = new Image(getApplicationContext());
        dbHelper.open();
        byte[] bytes = dbHelper.retreiveImageFromDB();
        dbHelper.close();
        DbBitmapUtility bmpU = new DbBitmapUtility();
        bmpU.getImage(bytes);
```

//// METHODS

```
public byte[] retreiveImageFromDB() {
        Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, IMAGES_TABLE, new String[]{IMAGE,},
                null, null, null, null,
                IMAGE_ID + " DESC", "1");
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(IMAGE));
            cur.close();
            return blob;
        }
        cur.close();
        return null;
    }


public Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
```

Now I need to somehow put the image as an email attachment.

How can I do that?

Comment: what email api are you using?

Comment: I'm sending email via Intent

Comment: `Intent sendImage = new Intent();
sendImage.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Image attachment");
sendImage.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getImage(retrieveImageFromDB());
this.startActivity(sendDoc);`


the first link on google search
 http://google.com/?q=android+send+email+with+image+attachment